# How do I remove spacing at the bottom of my site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am creating a website for our company.
I wanted the homepage to be like a simple landing page. Something similar to this site (https://www.agbaonline.com)
The challenge I am having is, the page has a white spacing at the bottom that just doesn't look nice at all. How do I get rid of this. I don't intend to put a footer in the page as I want it to be as straightforward as possible.
This is the link to the website, currently being worked on (https://www.mimshakspares.com/test) - we are using wordpress and the Gutenberg Block Builder.

Thank you for your assistance guys.

Comment: Post some code please

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `margin-bottom` of this class `.uagb-block-1d95c7fa.uagb-column__wrap`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've opened the code editor on the page but I'm not getting the class you mentioned in your answer, is there something I am doing wrong? sorry I am still new to this